# How can I import a partition from one table into another in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I would like to know if the following steps are possible and how fast this is:

1. Create a partition named part1 in Table A
2. Drop partition part1 in Table B
3. Import the Table A partition part1 into Table B

Can you provide me with an example if it is possible indeed? Or any resources I can look at?

Note that the tables would have the exact same structure.

Comment: Are the partitioning schemes compatible ? For example if range partitioned by date, does the part1 from tableA have the same dates as part2 from tableb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar with the [`ALTER TABLE ... EXCHANGE PARTITION`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2084770) command. This would exchange a single partition with a table that has the same structure.

A little example:

```
/* Partitionned Table Creation */
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_a (
  2     ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3     DATA VARCHAR2(200)
  4  )
  5  PARTITION BY RANGE (ID) (
  6     PARTITION part100 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
  7     PARTITION part200 VALUES LESS THAN (200)
  8  );

Table created

/* Swap table creation */
SQL> CREATE TABLE swap_table (
  2     ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3     DATA VARCHAR2(200)
  4  );

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO swap_table SELECT ROWNUM, 'a' FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 99;

99 rows inserted

SQL> select count(*) from table_a partition (part100);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

This will exchange the partition `part100` with the transition table `swap_table`:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE table_a EXCHANGE PARTITION part100 WITH TABLE swap_table;

Table altered

SQL> select count(*) from table_a partition (part100);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        99
```